# Set the value of an input field?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this:

```
<body>
    <header></header>
    <h1>Request Group Rate</h1> 
    <form>
        <input type="hidden" id="referrer">
        //...
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[id="referrer"]').val(document.referrer);
        });
    </script>
```

How so I set the value attribute of the `<input>` with `id="referrer"`?

Comment: What happens when you run the code shown? Looks like it should work *if you've included jquery.js on the page*, though `$('#referrer')` is a better way to select the element by its ID.

Comment: When selecting an element with an id use # as in `$('#referrer').val(...)`.

Comment: Works fine as-is.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I rolled back your edit because the OP's code as shown doesn't make it clear whether jQuery.js is included on the page, whereas in your edit you explicitly added that library. If that *was* the problem that edit makes the question hard to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[id=referrer]").attr('value', document.referrer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1>Request Group Rate</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="referrer" value="" style="width:100%">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This is not the recommended way to [set a value for an element using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: @ErikPhilips Bro!!! This is not recommended way but OP wants this way :-)
Please read post before down vote "How so I set the value attribute of the <input> with id="referrer"?"
by the way thank you for down vote:-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine and should work. You can try using # once.

```
$('#referrer').val(document.referrer);
```

Answer (score 0):

What sort of trouble are you having? because this works fine

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[id="referrer"]').val(document.referrer);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="referrer" style="width:100%">
</form>
```

Althought I would use:

```
$('#referrer').val(document.referrer);
```